# Why the email I send via the INSTRUCTOR > EMAILS is truncated?

Tags: openedx

**1) Given my email**, produced via a mailchimp online editor.

[image]

**2) I go to my openEdX, log in as administrator of the MOOC. Then got to `My MOOC` > `INSTRUCTOR` > `EMAILS`, in order to send my email**. First a test to myself, later to my 2000 mooc students.

[image]

**3) The email I receive in my inbox is CUT HALF WAY.** The bottom part is all missing.

[image]

**QUESTION : What is going on there ? How to fix this ?**

Comment: Note that it's "ambiguïté", and not "ambigüité" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Look into your code for the first paragraph which disapeared. It's likely the buggy part.

For this case, I can see the first disappeared sentence is :

> Astuce : Pensez à inviter NudiMooc à suivre votre BLOG

My eyes are catched up by the strange  sign, which is a rare unicode character.

**Delete this exotic  sign from your email / html5 code, and it will work again.** I tested it by sending to myself. Horray ! The corrected code without the lightbulb was complete !! :D

OpenEdX processing may crash on this string. But because there are some witty security, the previous, valid text is kept.